# Tyre came off car: who is liable?

Tags: tires

A customer came to you tyre garage a few days ago and had new tyres fitted, one of his alloys had a faulty stud. We contacted the customer's father while the car was still here. He said he was aware of this and had told his son to replace it, but he had not done so. We fitted the tyres and tightened studs (all work is on camera). 24 hours later his father rang to say the wheel came off the car and caused €600 worth of damage. Are we liable?

Comment: First find out what caused the problem ; one missing stud will not cause a wheel to come off ( unless it only had a total of 2 studs).

Comment: the customers father advised us that his son checked the studs when he brought the car home and re tightened them, but i don't have this in writing

Comment: joe, if the father told you this, he may be a useful witness in court. Also important is if a torque wrench was used. If not, the wrenching person holds a large portion of the responsibility. I agree about the 3 out of 4 and 4 out of 5 answer.

Comment: Liability may well be affected by what jurisdiction — state and country — you're in.

Comment: thank you for all your replies, they were very helpful, the issue has been resolved, there was an underlying problem as some of you suggested, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be more of a legal question so it may be worth speaking with your insurers or solicitor but I'd say you may find your paperwork may mitigate any claim.  If you have a copy of the job sheet, signed by the customer on collection, which clearly highlights the defect and notes that you spoke with a representative of the customer (the father) who was already aware of the fault and had advised he'd already told his son that the stud needed to be replaced.  Plus if you have CCTV footage of the customer collecting the car which shown clearly that you showed the customer the problem on the car and advised they had it repaired, you are likely fairly covered.  I'd also be interested to see what the job sheet and contract that the customer signed when dropping the vehicle in for the work stated.

What you need to demonstrate is that you had clearly explained the issue to the customer and advised them that the vehicle should not be driven until it was repaired.  If you can do this, I'd guess you'd be golden.

Out of interest, what did the customer collide with?  I'd personally ask the customer if they wanted me to speak to their insurer and advise them that you'd told them that the car should not be used on the road in the condition it was in.  Asking the customer this simple question may make the whole case evaporate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get professional legal advice, BUT I would suggest that YES you are.

The only safe options you had were:

1) to refuse to touch that wheel and do the other 3 only, until the customer had it repaired to the required standard, or

2) to get permission to repair that damage to the required standard - if they refused then don't touch it.

However, usually 4 out of 5 or even 3 out of 4 are normally sufficient to secure a wheel as a short term temporary measure, so perhaps there was some other damage...